Buf with protoc_builtin PHP has different behaviour than the actual protoc plugin?
I'm migrating a PHP project using protoc to the Buf CLI. To ensure backwards compatibility, I'm trying to have Buf produce more or less exactly the same output as the builtin PHP plugin would do.
I've configured my buf.gen.yaml to use protoc_builtin: php as the target plugin and left out any opts, as protoc also wasn't taking any arguments before.
When I run buf generate, but the GPBMetadata binary files are now in the wrong directory. protoc puts them in a directory at the top level of your output replicating your directory structure (not even your package path, just the directories).
Here's my directory structure:
src
| users
    | user.proto
| items
    | user_item.proto

Here's my config:
version: v2

managed:
  enabled: true

inputs:
  - directory: .
    paths:
      - src

plugins:
  - protoc_builtin: php
    out: buf_out

Running buf generate (with the above config) produces this output:
buf_out
| Users
    | User.php
    | Metadata
        | User.php
| Items
    | UserItem.proto
        | Metadata
            | UserItem.php

Running protoc -I=. php_out=builtin_out $(find src -type f -name '*proto') yields this:
builtin_out
| Metadata
    | Users
        | User.php
    | Items
        | User_item.proto
| Users
    | User.php
| Items
    | User_item.proto

Notice also the differences in Snakecase conversion. Clearly Buf is doing more than it's documentation is telling us.
Are there any flags to Buf that let me revert to the protoc behaviour. Or am I on the wrong version somehow? (using 1.45.0 btw)

Can you share both commands you are running?

While editing, I found the fix. You need to turn of managed mode and it reverts to the builtin behaviour.

You need to turn of managed mode to get the same behaviour as with protoc and its builtin plugins.
In your buf.gen.yaml inside the managed block set enabled: false or delete the block altogether.
